# SSL Yii connection to postgresql Google cloud database

Tags: php, postgresql, yii2, ssl-certificate, google-cloud-sql

I’m newbie user of Yii and I need to connect my Yii2 application to a Google cloud database (postgres). I need to made the connection using the SSL certificates I already have. I have all the credentials (host, user, 3x ssl, etc).

The thing is I’m able to connect to this remote google database using both PgAdmin client and the Google SDK console (Google Shell), but I can’t connect my Yii2 application to this database. I read a lot of documentation and found nothing.

- This is what I have in my common/config/main-local.php (Yii2 advanced configuration), I added the field 'attributes', just in case it works, but as I thought is not working:

  ```
  'db' => [
      'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',       
      'dsn' => 'pgsql:host=my-host;dbname=my-db-name',
      'attributes' => [
          PDO::PGSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY => 'path/to/my/client-key.pem',
          PDO::PGSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT => 'path/to/my/client-cert.pem',
          PDO::PGSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => 'path/to/my/server-ca.pem',
      ],
      'username' => 'myusername',
      'password' => 'mypassword',
      'charset' => 'utf8',
  ],
  ```
- This is how I connect through Google Shell, this works:

> psql "sslmode=verify-ca sslrootcert=path/to/my/server-ca.pem sslcert=path/to/my/client-cert.pem sslkey=path/to/my/client-key.pem hostaddr=google-instance-host user=david.tamarit dbname=google-db-name"`

Then, I put my password and I'm connected to my database in Google shell.

- In PgAdmin, I pass my credentials and I connect to the database, this works too.

How can I connect to my google cloud database using Yii?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show us what is your connection config so we can fix it if needed (remember to remove credentials)

Comment: Sorry...I edited the post, now you can see the code

Comment: What's in the error log for this?

Comment: With the field 'attributes' I get this:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined class constant 'PGSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY' in C:\xampp\htdocs\myt-migracion\common\config\main-local.php:10 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\myt-migracion\frontend\web\index.php(12): require() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\myt-migracion\common\config\main-local.php on line 10

Comment: If I comment the 'attributes' field, I get this Yii exception:

Database Exception – yii\db\Exception
SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL: connection requires a valid client certificate
FATAL: pg_hba.conf rejects connection for host "xxx.xx.xx.xx", user "myusername", database "mydbname", SSL off

Answer (score 2):

Since the DB is not on your machine there is no need for you to have PostgreSQL installed and this is the reason (I think) that these constants are not recognised. Try this:

```
'attributes' => [
    'sslmode' => 'verify-ca',
    'sslkey' => 'path/to/my/client-key.pem',
    'sslcert' => 'path/to/my/client-cert.pem',
    'sslrootcert' => 'path/to/my/server-ca.pem',
],
```

Comment: I tried right now and got the same error: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL: connection requires a valid client certificate
FATAL: pg_hba.conf rejects connection for host...

Comment: Note: I tried this: 'PDO::PGSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY => 'path/to/my/client-key.pem'' from an example of a MYSQL database connection that requires ssl, I even don't know if it's possible with a postgres database, or if it's like that, I tried just in case because I found nothing...

Comment: I've added one key to my answer, could you check if it works now?

Comment: Still got the same error... it has to be possible in some way since I did it from 2 different ways, but I need yo connect my application to the DB...it should be super simple since you only need to pass the credentials like any other app/db... I'll keep looking for a solution

Comment: OK, I tried this and it seems it works! I'm connected to the remote google db. I put the psql (pgsql) command into the dsn parameter like that:
'db' => [
            'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
            'dsn' => 'pgsql:sslmode=verify-ca sslrootcert=path/to/my/server-ca.pem sslcert=path/to/my/client-cert.pem sslkey=path/to/my/client-key.pem hostaddr=xx.xxx.xx.xxx user=my-user password=my-passworddbname=my-dbname',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ],